# JSON - changing the key value pair based on users input

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the users input and make it a part of the json I'm building, what I want to achieve is like this.

When the user fills the textbox, I could get that value and alert it? however currently the output that I'm getting is only "[object HTMLInputElement]".

Here's my code and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3a4f/
Any COmment Suggestions is appreciated:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function Run() {
             var x = document.getElementById("fruits");

                var data = {"fruits": x};
                alert(data.fruits);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="fruits">
        <button onClick="Run()">Run</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.value` for the element: http://jsfiddle.net/u3a4f/1/

```
function Run() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fruits");

    var data = {
        "fruits": x.value
    };
    alert(data.fruits);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
var x = document.getElementById("fruits").value;
```

EDIT:
document.getElementById returns a javascript DOM element object. If you desire to access any attribute like id,class,value etc. you have to access using "." operator like for class it is

```
document.getElementById("fruits").class
```

Similarly to get the value of an element(in this case the element is input so it has value attribute), you must use

```
document.getElementById("fruits").value
```

Comment: Why should they? Explain

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Run() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fruits").value;
  var data = {"fruits": x};
  alert(data.fruits);
}
```

Read more about [HTML Input element: MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)